# How to request gRPC server made by Go running on Cloud Run

Tags: docker, go, google-cloud-platform, grpc, google-cloud-run

I made gRPC server by go lang.
https://github.com/takat0-h0rikosh1/grpc-with-go

It's a cafe-cli application.

I registered container to GCR, and deploy to Cloud Run.

```sh
# docker build
docker build -t cafe .

# register image
$ docker tag cafe gcr.io/xxx/cafe
$ docker push gcr.io/xxx/cafe 

# deploy to cloud run
$ gcloud beta run deploy --project xxx --image gcr.io/xxx/cafe
Please choose a target platform:
 [1] Cloud Run (fully managed)
 [2] Cloud Run for Anthos deployed on Google Cloud
 [3] Cloud Run for Anthos deployed on VMware
 [4] cancel
Please enter your numeric choice:  1

To specify the platform yourself, pass `--platform managed`. Or, to make this the default target platform, run `gcloud config set run/platform managed`.

Service name (cafe):  cafe-service
Allow unauthenticated invocations to [cafe-service] (y/N)?  N

Deploying container to Cloud Run service [cafe-service] in project [xxx] region [us-central1]
✓ Deploying new service... Done.
  ✓ Creating Revision...
  ✓ Routing traffic...
Done.
Service [cafe-service] revision [cafe-service-00001-pal] has been deployed and
is serving 100 percent of traffic at https://cafe-service-xxx-uc.a.run.app
```

How to request to this gRPC server?
I tried the following.

```sh
$ curl -H \
  "Authorization: Bearer (gcloud auth print-identity-token)" \
  https://cafe-service-xxx-uc.a.run.app

<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>401 Unauthorized</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Unauthorized</h1>
<h2>Your client does not have permission to the requested URL <code>/</code>.</h2>
<h2></h2>
</body></html>

$ grpcurl -plaintext cafe-service-xxx-uc.a.run.app:443 list
Failed to dial target host "cafe-service-xxx-uc.a.run.app:443": context deadline exceeded

$ grpcurl -authority (gcloud auth print-identity-token) -plaintext cafe-service-xxx-uc.a.run.app:443 list
Failed to dial target host "cafe-service-xxx-uc.a.run.app:443": context deadline exceeded
```

What must I do?

Comment: Is this a Unary stream? Do you have Cloud Run Invoker role attached to the IAM member (service account) for which you are generating the Identity Token?

Comment: deploy your service with the flag `--allow-unauthenticated`

Comment: you forgot a `$` around `(` `)`.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere that would not be required since here and explicit authentication token is passed to authenticate as the user's Google account.

Comment: @AhmetB-Google You are right I didn't see this. And yes, the $ has been forgotten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to try is to get things going is create a new service and allow unauthenticated:

> "Allow unauthenticated invocations to [] (y/N)?  y"

Secondly, if you would try to access gRPC with auth, please check:

https://medium.com/google-cloud/grpc-authentication-with-cloud-run-72e4d6c44739

Answer (score 0):

The Authorization header in your curl command is wrong. It's missing a `$` before the gcloud command. Use this instead:

```
curl -H \
  "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)" \
  https://cafe-service-xxx-uc.a.run.app
```

Comment: Because of I use fish terminal, It isn't missing.

Comment: If you are using fish terminal you need to escape the quotes. `curl -H \
  "Authorization: Bearer "(gcloud auth print-identity-token)`